# Expect syntax error ./auto.sh ./auto.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `}' ./auto.sh: line 12: `}'

Tags: bash, shell

Got out of `#!/usr/bin/expect -f` and `#!/bin/bash`; now I got the error:

```
./autom.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./autom.sh: line 7: `"*\#"  { send "cd /var-tmp"; send "./scmd.sh -tmp /var/tmp -plugins /var/tmp/plugins -dmore \r";  }'
```

Code:

```
set i 0
IP_FILE="./hst.txt"

for i in `cat $IP_FILE`; do
sapwn ssh "@$i"
expect {
"*\#"  { send "cd /var-tmp"; send "./scmd.sh -tmp /var/tmp -plugins /var/tmp/plugins -dmore \r";  }
 "*\#" { puts "ejecucion exitosa" }
}
EOD
done>>logfile.txt`
```

Comment: Remove `#!/usr/bin/expect` as only one shebang of bash is required

Comment: Your question was confusingly formatted; I hope I've improved it.  I changed a `./utom.sh` to `./autom.sh` — how did the name switch while you were posting?  (Also, the title references `./auto.sh` but the body references `./autom.sh` — please be consistent!)  You should probably fix the spelling of `spawn` (it isn't `sapwn`).  You have some `expect`-like code masquerading as shell script; that is causing the errors.  Did you forget to run `expect` somewhere along the line?  Maybe `expect << EOD` after `do` and before `sapwn` or `spawn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fixing how you interface between bash and expect, it's easier just to stop using expect at all:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip_file=hst.txt

while read -r ip; do
  ssh "$ip" 'bash -s' <<'EOF'
cd /var-tmp || { echo "Could not cd to /var-tmp" >&2; exit 1; }
./scmd.sh -tmp /var/tmp -plugins /var/tmp/plugins -dmore
EOF
done <"$ip_file" >>logfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bash script which has expect code mixed into it. Based on the errant `EOD` there I'm guessing that is supposed to be a HERE document but you've lost the actual expect invocation. Maybe try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set i 0
IP_FILE="./hst.txt"

for i in `cat $IP_FILE`; do
expect - <<EOD
spawn ssh "@$i"
expect {
"*\#"  { send "cd /var-tmp\r"; send "./scmd.sh -tmp /var/tmp -plugins /var/tmp/plugins -dmore \r";  }
 "*\#" { puts "ejecucion exitosa" }
}
EOD
done>>logfile.txt
```

Edit: Added a `\r` after your first cd command and fixed the spelling of `spawn`.

Edit#2: And, as @CharlesDuffy mentioned, reading lines with `for` is not a good idea. Something like this is better:

```
#!/bin/bash

set i 0
IP_FILE="./hst.txt"

while read -r i; do
expect - <<EOD
sapwn ssh "@$i"
expect {
"*\#"  { send "cd /var-tmp"; send "./scmd.sh -tmp /var/tmp -plugins /var/tmp/plugins -dmore \r";  }
 "*\#" { puts "ejecucion exitosa" }
}
EOD
done < "$IP_FILE" >> logfile.txt
```